Monochromatic Triangles with Lattice Centroids in $\mathbb{Z}^2 $
There is this problem proving that every $2$-colouring of the lattice points of $\mathbb R^m$ has a collection of $n$ monochromatic points whose centroid is a lattice point of the same colour and I was wondering if we can generalise it for a triangle but colour the grid of lattice points using $n$ colours.
The proof for the case with 2 colours it covered here: Every $2$-colouring of the lattice points of $\mathbb R^m$ has $n$ monochromatic points whose centroid is a lattice point of the same colour
Prove that for any n-coloring of the points in $ \mathbb{Z}^2 $, the two-dimensional integer lattice, there exists a monochromatic triangle whose vertices are lattice points of the same color, and whose centroid is also a lattice point of that same color.
Any help is appreciated it.

I would guess that it's a difficult question - one one hand, you have posed it with $n$ colours, and on the other hand, you ask for the centroid to be also a lattice point. Did you find it as an exercise in a book, or are you just pondering about it? A way to start thinking about it could be try it on $\mathbb R^2$ first

@SayanDutta I remember seeing this question asked on the internet if the case with the triangle is possible

Consider a degenerate triangle $\Delta ABC$, where points $A, B, C$ are collinear, let's suppose on line $[Ox$. So the coordinates of the points are $A(a,0), B(b,0), C(c,0)$.
We can now use van der Waerden's theorem which states that if we colour $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with $n$ diffren colours, there always exists be an arithmetic progression of lenght $k, \forall k\geq3$, so you can choose $a,b,c$ to be an arithmetic progression and the points $A,B,C$ to be monochromatic. Also, the centroid of triangle $\Delta ABC$ is $B$, so the centroid will also have the same colour.
